# How to change Appearance in GWT

Tags: gwt, design-patterns, appearance

I started working with GWT and I have to change the total appearance of the components. I found the "Appearance Pattern" and some explanation, but there is not a good example.
I looked this url: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CellBackedWIdgets and the best explanaition that I found was with GXT library in http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-gwt-3-appearance-design.

My question is: Is there a better example of how to change the appearance (like the GXT tutorial) but using only GWT, without any libraries ???

If someone knows about this theme, please help me!
Thank you.

Comment: FYI, for now, only one widget in GWT proper uses the appearance pattern: the `ButtonBase` (abstract, `TextButton` is the only subclass).

Comment: mmm I will take a look of that Class.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By appearance, if you mean color theme, you can change or remove the default theme in your `PROJECTNAME.gwt.xml` file. Changing/removing this will respectively change/remove the CSS stylesheet that gets automatically attached to your application.

The default is:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
```

You can change it to one of the following themes:

```
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>
```

Or remove / comment those lines altogether.

Comment: One of the reasons I'm working in GWT is because you can see the objects in all browsers in the same way. By modifying the CSS with the method you say, is still maintained this property?

Comment: Sorry @Milena, I don't fully understand your question. 
But if you use my method, a uniform theme will be applied to ALL the GWT widgets, on all browsers. You also have the option of making your own theme, which is harder to do than using my method.

Comment: @Milena changing to one of the other built in themes will maintain that property. I'm not sure that removing the theme will as it depends on what you provide as your custom theme.